# Plotting CSV data on a map in Python

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib-basemap, netcdf4, read.csv

I have to plot data from 1200 isotopic measuring stations (worldwide) in a map for a thesis. For this I have downloaded them in a CSV file. Afterwards I have divided this large CSV file into smaller CSV files, each of them containing the data taken in the same month and year.
The next steps of my work are to interpolate the data and then plot them in a map.

Since I want my map to look like this map: https://joehamman.com/2013/10/12/plotting-netCDF-data-with-Python/  I have to transfer the CSV files into NetCDF files.

Do you have a good approach how I can do this, or is this step even necessary and will I be able to plot the data without this conversion with a comparable result to the link?
You would help me a lot!

Comment: Hello, it is not clear which map in the link you are referring to.. also could you provide an example row of the CSV column?

High level thoughts would be to load the CSV into Geopandas and then plot on a map using Ipyleaflet

Comment: Hi Sam Murphy,
I just found out that I can also answer you here but you can find the lists or the more explicit link in the answer below. 
all the best

Comment: hey, there's certainly no need to convert your data to NetCDF  (it's a data-storage format... there's hardly any benefit in using it as an intermediate data-structure for plotting except if your plotting-libraries are only capable of ingesting NetCDF like datasets)  If you search for a quick way to visualize your data, have a look at [EOmaps](https://github.com/raphaelquast/EOmaps)! (I'm the dev)